# A SPARQL question - How can I improve this query?

Tags: statistics, sparql, opendata

I have put the filter parameter, the LSOA code E01001117, in the PREFIX.  I guess this is not best practice?
Although the query work, I am not convinced I have an optimal query.
Any comments welcome!

```
# endpoint= https://opendatacommunities.org/sparql

PREFIX lsoa: <http://opendatacommunities.org/id/geography/administration/lsoa/E01001117>
PREFIX adminGeo: <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/admingeo/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX pmd: <http://publishmydata.com/def/ontology/foi/>
SELECT ?LSOACD ?LSOANM ?LSOAstatus ?LADCD ?LADNM 
WHERE { 
  lsoa: adminGeo:inDistrict ?LAD .
  lsoa: skos:notation ?LSOACD .
  lsoa: pmd:displayName ?LSOANM .
  lsoa: skos:note ?LSOAstatus .
  ?LAD pmd:code ?LADCD .
  ?LAD pmd:displayName ?LADNM .
} LIMIT 10
```

Comment: that is not a "filter" in a SPARQL sense. You just used a prefix declaration for a full URI - that is bad practice. It's neither useful nor harmful from a performance perspective, but it's uncommon. The "better" way would be to use the prefix just for the namespace up to the local name and then write `lsoa:E01001117` - the query itself can indeed be made more compact but don#t repeating the subject.

Comment: UninformedUser is obviously correct. If you were confused by URIs like  `<http://opendatacommunities.org/id/geography/administration/lsoa/E01001117/geometry>`, you can shorten them as `lsoa:E01001117\/geometry`.